# Confirmation of Uncertainty in Indices New Formula?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, error-analysis

> I am experimenting relations with regards of the value with uncertainty raised to the $n$th power.
>   I came up with this formula: $$(A\pm\alpha)^n=A^n\pm(A^{n-1}n\alpha)$$
>   Anyone here able to confirm if correct or not?

I made this equation by myself and when I tested it, the values are similar compared to the method my teacher shows me.
Example: Find $y^5$ given $y=2.0\pm0.1$

Solution using my teacher's method:

$(2.0\pm0.1)^5=(2.0\pm5\%)^5=(32\pm(5\times5\%))=32(\pm25\%)=32(\pm8)$

Solution using the equation above:

$(2.0\pm0.1)^5$

$A=2.0$

$\alpha=0.1$

$n=5$

Substituting these numbers become: $2.0^5(\pm0.2^{5-1}\times5\times0.1)=32(\pm16\times0.5)=32(\pm8)$

Comment: Important point it's not clear you appreciate: The only $=$ sign in your formula, and the second $=$ sign in your teacher's, are both $\approx$. Both your statements, as statements about pure arithmetic, are wrong; they are just approximations for small $\alpha/A$. By chance, though, the formulas are exactly the ones you're supposed to use according to [error propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty), where $\alpha$ is the standard deviation of $A$ and $nA^{n-1}\alpha$ is the standard deviation of $A^n$.

Answer (score 0):

The way we work out this problem is to start by taking a factor of $A^n$ out of the brackets (I'm going to use $A+\alpha$ rather than $A\pm\alpha$ to keep things simple):

$$ (A + \alpha)^n = A^n \left( 1 + \frac{\alpha}{A} \right)^n $$

Now we expand the right hand side using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):

$$ A^n \left( 1 + \frac{\alpha}{A} \right)^n  = A^n \left( 1 + n\frac{\alpha}{A} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} \left(\frac{\alpha}{A}\right)^2 + ... \right) $$

Typically the error $\alpha$ is much less than $A$ so the ratio $\alpha/A$ is much less than one. If $\alpha/A$ is much less than one then $(\alpha/A)^2$ is much, much less than one and we can ignore it and all higher powers. Our expression simplifies to:

$$\begin{align}
 (A + \alpha)^n &\approx A^n \left( 1 + n\frac{\alpha}{A} \right) \\
                &= A^n + A^n n\frac{\alpha}{A} \\
                &= A^n + A^{n-1} n\alpha
\end{align}$$

Which is the same expression that you got.

The expression becomes clearer if we use percentage errors. If we write $\varepsilon$ as the percentage error, so e.g. $\varepsilon_A = \alpha/A$, then we get:

$$ \varepsilon_{A^n} = n \varepsilon_A $$